# Is there a way to clone a Profile via API?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, profile, custom-profile, deployment-api

When using Salesforce UI, it's possible to clone a Profile. This is handy, because we can clone the `Minimum Access - Salesforce` Profile which includes almost the bare minimum permissions.

However, while creating a new Profile via the Metadata API, even though the Metadata in itself is almost empty, lots of Permissions/Tab access/Objects access will be provided.

To avoid that, I would like to clone an existing Profile to be sure no extra permissions will be added at creation.

Is there a way to clone an existing Profile using any Salesforce API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [readMetadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_readMetadata.htm). You specify the metadata type and fullName and this will pull down the entire profile including objects, fields, etc.

What I do is I use a Chrome extension called [Wizdler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wizdler/oebpmncolmhiapingjaagmapififiakb?hl=en) and then navigate to Setup -> Integrations -> API and then click on the Metadata WSDL.

From there the Wizdler Chrome Extension should parse the WSDL and then allow you to generate the request to retrieve the profile:

[image]

[image]

You will have to grab your session Id (I do this via Browser Cookies) and replace the target URL at the top with your domain

Comment: That's not as easy as just having a clone operation, but it looks like that I can make it work like this. I was aware of Profile Metadata in the Tooling API, but not via this readMetadata operation and it seems to contain everything I need to script that, thanks ! I'll accept it as best answer as I think it's the closest we can get from cloning with actual Salesforce APIs.

Comment: Yeah this is the "old" synchronous metadata API. You can def clone an entire profile this way. I have also done the same thing in a nodeJS program via JSForce (https://jsforce.github.io/document/#read-metadata)

Comment: That's what I used to try your answer, working fine :)